# Customized UITableViewCell reuse with childviewcontroller issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have create a UITableView With a Customized TableViewCell,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Equipment.h"
#import "MCStepperViewController.h"

@class EquipmentCell;

@protocol EquipmentCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)EquipmentCell:(EquipmentCell *)cell didChangeStepperValue:(int)stepperValue indexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;

@end

@interface EquipmentCell : UITableViewCell <MCStepperDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* eqiupmentImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* details;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* prices;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MCStepperViewController* stepper;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <EquipmentCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSIndexPath* indexPath;

-(void)setContent:(Equipment*)equip;
-(void)setAmount:(int)eq_amount;
@end
```

The customized cell owns a stepperview controller, and I add the stepperViewController.view to the content view of the cell.

The stepperViewController has a textField and two buttons as strong properties.

The confusing part is, when I scroll the table view, the table cells are ready for reuse process.

The property views of the cell works well, but the view of stepperViewController, which is the subview of the contentView, is becoming duplicate.

Although I have set cell.stepper.view.textField to the right value, but it still doesn't work.

Is there any good solution? I don't think disable reusability is a good attempt.

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

The cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
else if (tableView == _subTable)
{
    EquipmentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailTable" forIndexPath:indexPath ];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[EquipmentCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"detailTable"];
    }
    cell.indexPath = indexPath;
    Equipment* item = [[[_goodsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.delegate = self;
    [cell setContent:item];
    if (countDic) {
        if ([countDic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (indexPath.section*100)+(indexPath.row)]]) {
            [cell setAmount:(int)[[countDic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (indexPath.section*100)+(indexPath.row)]] integerValue]];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell setAmount:0];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I tried to assign the textfield.text in cell class, but is doesn't work.

```
- (void)setAmount:(int)eq_amount
{
    _stepper.amount = eq_amount;
    _stepper.amountText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", eq_amount];
    if (eq_amount == self.stepper.min) {
        _stepper.minusButton.hidden = YES;
        _stepper.amountText.hidden = YES;
     }
}
```

Comment: where do you add the stepperViewController.view to the content view of the cell.

Comment: @ZHZ in the instancetype method.  - (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier in the customized cell class.

Comment: can you post that code as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Check where you add your stepperViewController.view to the content view of the cell.

You want to support view recycling for your tableview cell. So as soon as your cell1 is not visible anymore and data 2 needs a cell (cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called), this reused cell will be cell 1. Instead of data1 cell1 now displays data2. If you add the stepperViewController.view in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function, there will be the view added for data1. now if cell1 isn't visible anymore and should be used for data2 you should check if you add the stepperViewController.view again.

Instead of simply adding the view, you could check if there is already a stepperViewController.view in you cell's subviews and remove or reuse it.

Comment: I add the stepperViewController.view in the intancetype method of the customized cell. I attempted to set the tag of the stepperController.view and try to get the view using viewWithTag in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, and set the textField of that view with tag, but it doesn't work.